# help with regex

Tags: java, regex

From the string `[foo](bar)` I want to extract the `foo` and the `bar` part:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)");
String input = "[foo](bar)";
assert p.matcher(input).matches();
String[] a = ???   // should be initialized to {"foo", "bar"}
```

What do I write in the fourth line to obtain `foo` and `bar` from the input?

Comment: You should use the p.matcher(input) which returns you a [matcher](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) object, which contains your matches. And then you can use find() for trying to find the next one in the string and group() to access last found one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should get you close to where you wanna be:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]\\((.*)\\)");
String input = "[foo](bar)";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if (m.find()){
    String[] a = { m.group(1), m.group(2) }; 
}
```

Essentially, you will create a `Matcher`.  Then use `find()` to locate the match.  Then you will use the groups to find the things that were matched inside of the parenthesis.

Comment: Why do regex groups count from 1!? However: +1

Comment: @Martijn, because group 0 will hold the entire match.

Answer (score 0):

I would say a regex like below is easier to handle and extend:

```
[\[\(](.*?)[\]\)]
```

Comment: But that matches just a part of the string, and it also matches invalid parts like `(foo]`

Comment: @Bart Kiers - I know you are right, but I still want to say that the OP asked for extracting foo and bar.